# TCP Server C++ program

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am working on a simple Server program in C++ for my class. Our professor gave us skeleton code to follow, along with instructions in the comments. I finished it, and it compiles in Unix, but I am having problems with password authentication from the client. It is written so it hits every possible option, but still doesn't print result. Here's the function from the program. (I can supply the whole function if necessary). So my question, is my logic flawed, or is it some little bug?

```
//  PURPOSE:  To send 'GOOD_PASSWORD_RESPONSE' to the client over socket file
//  descriptor 'clientFD' and return 'true' if the password 'read()' from
//  'clientFD' matches 'password', or to send 'BAD_PASSWORD_RESPONSE' to
//  the client and return 'false' otherwise.
bool didLogin(int clientFD, const char *password) {
    //  I.  Application validity check:
    printf("Process %d authenticating user . . .\n", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);

    //  II.  See if user successfully logged-in:
    //  II.A.  Obtain user's password:

    char buffer[MAX_LINE];
    size_t size = sizeof(buffer);
    read(clientFD, buffer, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    }
    //  II.B.  Handle when user's password does NOT match:
    if (strncmp(buffer, password, MAX_PASSWORD_LEN) != 0) {
        strncpy(BAD_PASSWORD_RESPONSE, buffer, MAX_LINE);
        printf("Process %d bad password.\n", getpid());

        return (false);
    }

    //  II.C.  If get here then user's password does match:
    strncpy(GOOD_PASSWORD_RESPONSE, buffer, MAX_LINE);
    printf("Process %d good password.\n", getpid());

    //  III.  Finished:

    return (true);
}
```

Comment: what excellent examples on how not to use C++; how not to do authentication; how not use raw buffers without proper initialization/size parameters; how not to mix business logic with protocol implementation (transport details). Hint: return value of `read` is ignored. That should probably not happen

Comment: @sehe lol, 'should probably not happen'; it pretty much screws up everything:)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know its not the way to do it correctly, but I had to strictly adhere to the skeleton code provided.

Comment: Can you leave derogatory comments in the code to compensate :/

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with your code. Here are the first few I noticed:

1. You do not use the return value of `read()`. This return value tells you how many bytes were *actually* read.
2. You are using `strncmp()` to compare the maximum password length. What if the password you're matching against is shorter than the maximum?
3. You seem to mix up the `dest` and `src` parameters of `strncpy()` in a couple of places.

Answer (score 1):

Your code excerpt is too short to analyze fully, but I see several likely problems.

1) It's obvious that `clientFD` is a socket. A `read`() request on a socket, or on any file descriptor for that matter, is not guaranteed to read, and return the requested number of bytes. Your `read`() call may, and in fact likely will, return fewer than `size` bytes.

2) Your code assumes that `read`() will always return `size` number of bytes read, and will attempt to print every byte. Since it's likely that fewer bytes would have read, your code will read, and attempt to print, uninitialized memory. Undefined behavior.

3) It's unclear what `GOOD_PASSWORD_RESPONSE` and `BAD_PASSWORD_RESPONSE` is. That last statement in your code looks wrong.

Comment: ..and the almost inevitable calling of str*() on buffers that are not securely null-terminated, (by-product of ignoring the result returned by read).